# Multiple object position lock

Tags: modeling

I have a little problem: I want to lock in position (position,rotating, and scale) a lot of objects and unlock only the one I have to work on.
Is there any way to lock/unlock multiple objects with only one click?
Sometimes happens to move as a mistake some parts (my file has around 3500 parts and it should be good to keep them separated).
I'm not an expert but I can't find it.

Thanks to all

Comment: Hey :). You can lock objects from selecting, but perhaps *View > Local View* is closer to what you want.

Comment: Can select them all and alt+click on the lock buttons (be sure "emulate 3 button mouse" is off in preferences).

Comment: Many thanks...it works.